# Javascript: Cookie can not be read in all the HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I copied and used getCookie and setCookie from W3Schools(http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Here are the codes of get and set:

```
  function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
  {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
  }

  function getCookie(c_name)
  {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
      c_value = null;
    }
    else
    {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
      var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
   if (c_end == -1)
   {
      c_end = c_value.length;
   }
      c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
   }
      return c_value;
 }
```

I frist set cookie in prepareDrive.html page

```
 setCookie("pathName",path,365);
 setCookie("formatName",ifFormat,365);
```

Then I called get cookie in startInstall.html page which is a different HTML page

```
 var path = getCookie("pathName");
 var ifFormat = getCookie("formatName");
```

but both path and ifFormat are null. However, when I console.log in prepareDrive.html, the data is there. Thanks !!! This is my first time to use cookie in JS. I do not want to use localstorage to store data.Because some old version browsers do not support this function ,right?

Comment: Here's a tip. W3Schools is a pretty horrible resource to learn from (http://w3fools.com) . There are plenty of questions here on SO that explain how to handle cookies, as well as a decent tutorial on MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) and a bunch of decent libraries that work (jQuery cookies if you're into _that_ sort of thing, or Cookies.js which I just used today and was nice). W3Schools are just really good with SEO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a common `path` for the cookie. Simplest is just to specify the domain root:

```
var c_value=escape(value) + "; path=/" + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
```

Without that, `document.cookie` will [default to the current `location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#Syntax), making the cookie only available to the current page.

> ;path=*path* (e.g., '/', '/mydir') If not specified, defaults to the current path of the current document location.

---

Also, I suggest having a look at the "[*little framework*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support)" for cookies on MDN.

Comment: Thanks, but after I added path, it still shows null. And even show null in current html page. Here is how I check the error, maybe I am wrong. After setCookie("pathName",path,365); I called console.log("get cookie information = " + getCookie("pathName")); immediately. And it printed out null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jquery you might want to consider the jquery plugin:

https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com

That makes it pretty straightforward.